# Moshe after t'chiyas hamesim

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, resurrection-of-the-dead

After [the resurrection of the dead](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9335), will *Moshe* have any particular role? If so, what will it be? Sources, please.

(The question was inspired a popular song whose lyrics include "*Moshe rabenu* will lead us once again in *Y'rushalayim b'ezras Hashem*", but is of independent interest.)

Comment: @msh210 After Moshiach we may want/need to bring korbonos. We are all now tmei'i maisim. So before entering the Temple, we will need to be purified through having the ashes of the Poroh Adumoh sprinkled on us on the third and seventh days. Day 1 is the day we decide to separate ourselves from tumas mais. The word of ordinary people that they have separated from tumah on Day 1 will not be accepted. Instead they will have to "check in" with specifically Moshe and Aaron on day 1. Here then is a role for Moshe after Moshiach.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61955

Answer (score 8):

From [Yoma 5b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=6&daf=5b&format=pdf), it seems that he will again re-dress the kohanim (or, at least, Aharon and his sons) in their kohanic clothing.

[Niddah 70b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=70b&format=pdf) also mentions him (according to one version of R. Yehoshua's answer) as being the one to decide whether those revived at techiyas hameisim will need to be sprinkled with parah adumah water. [Although according to the explanation given by the Lubavitcher Rebbe zt"l [(Likkutei Sichos 18:249)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15975&pgnum=258), the point of mentioning him there is that whether he reappears alone or together with the Jews who died in the desert will be a factor in determining whether they need such sprinkling; according to this approach, then, the halachic decision won't necessarily be in his hands.]

Answer (score 3):

I recently saw quoted in the name of [the *Tzemach Tzedek* of Lubavitch](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31595&pgnum=246) the idea that *l'viyim* will be *kohanim* and the conjecture that *Moshe* will thus be *kohen gadol*.

Comment: I thought the Bechorim were supposed to resume that role. Also, don't you mean "Moshe will thus be kohen gadol again"? Wasn't he K"G before Aharon was chosen?

Comment: That is interesting, because the Rebbe explains this idea (about the leviim becoming kohanim - incidentally, it comes from Arizal) differently: the present-day leviim will be reborn (reincarnated) into kohanic families (see [Lessons In Tanya, ch. 50, footnote 16](http://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7929/jewish/Chapter-50.htm#footnote16a7929)). So I wonder how he would explain this statement of the Tzemach Tzedek, which seems to be saying that Moshe himself will actually change roles.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/to-live-and-live-again/07.htm) (note 213):

[Devarim Rabbah (3:16)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&st=&pgnum=180), states that Moshe Rabbeinu will come together with Eliyahu HaNavi. [The Midrash (2:10)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14384&st=&pgnum=168) also states that Moshe was buried in the desert together with his people so that upon Resurrection he will lead them all to the Land. Combining these two Midrashim, it would seem that Moshe together with his whole generation will be resurrected and will appear with Eliyahu upon the arrival of Mashiach. (See [Lev Chaim I:32.](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1587&st=&pgnum=242))

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere toward the end of Rosh HaShanah, when discussing Techias HaMeisim, the Gemara poses a Hava Aminah that only those in Eretz Yisrael would be awakened. The Gemara rejects this, saying that people like Moshe wouldn't have a share in Yimos HaMashiach if that were the case. I believe that, if not the Gemara itself, some Peirush on that Gemara adds that Moshe will once again lead the Dor HaMidbar and this time actually make it to Eretz Yisrael. I apologize for not being more specific about the sources; it's been a long time since I've learned Rosh HaShanah; I'll try, bli neder, to update this with sources over the next couple of days.