# Source for the description of Mashiach in MBD's "Some Day"

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, music

Mordechai Ben David's classic song "[Some Day](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xN7rm_ETjiQ)" gives a description of what will happen in *Yemot HaMashiach* (the days of Mashiach). It seems to be a very popular song, and has doubtlessly influenced many people's perceptions of Mashiach.

But are there sources in classic Jewish texts that this is based on?

I'm specifically wondering about the chorus (quoted from [Jewish Music Lyrics](http://jewishmusiclyrics.blogspot.co.il/2007/05/someday-well-all-be-together.html)):

> Someday we will all be together
>   Someday we'll be sheltered and warm
>   Never will we have to express any fear
>   Our scars and our wounds will disappear
>
> Avraham and Yitzchok will be there to greet us
>   Yaakov and his sons will stand by and smile
>   [Moshe Rabbeinu will lead us once again
> in Yerushalayim - B'Ezras Hashem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12376/moshe-after-tchiyas-hamesim?lq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer -- I had a couple of these handy.

Someday we will all be together [He must gather all the Jews back to the Land of Israel (Is. 43:5-6)]

Someday we'll be sheltered and warm
 Never will we have to express any fear [He must usher in an era of world peace and bring an end to war/fear(Is. 2:4)]

The second stanza is clearly starting with a generalized notion of techiyas hameisim. The specifics of who will lead goes beyond that.

Comment: Dear all:  Please [edit] the answer and fill in the rest of the requested information.