# Kohanim and Leviyim switching roles in the future

Tags: kohen-priest, messiah, levites-leviyim, latid-lavo-future, ymoth-hamoshiach

I once was told that at the time of Moshiach, the kohanim will become leviyim, and the leviyim will become kohanim with regards to their service in the third temple. I was told it was because Moshe Rabbeinu was supposed to be the Kohane Gadol, and asked Hashem that his brother, Aron, take his place. Then at the time of Moshiach, it will be accorded to the Leviyim to service in the beis hamikdash as kohanim, the true order as intended by Hashem. Where is this source from?

Comment: Hello C R, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for your first question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 
I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: Where did you see this reference? Even if the descendants of Moshe Rabbeinu were to become kohanim, why should the rest of the tribe of Levi replace the kohanim and why should the descendants of Aharon lose their status?

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28295

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15840

Comment: @msh210 Isn’t your latter comment an answer?