# Our bodies aren't here for the long haul?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, messiah, soul

I seem to have learnt something a long time ago. In basic terms that after the coming of Moshiach and the resurrection of the dead there will be a time where we won't need our bodies and we will live just with our souls. I.e. our bodies won't exist anymore. Does anyone know the source for this idea, I just can't pinpoint the exact place.

To put the question in basic terms.

- Our world with bodies.
- Moshiach comes
- Resurrection of the dead
- Our bodies dissipate. We just live by our souls.

Does anyone know if such an idea exists?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9340/603

Comment: @Menachem why not copypaste that as an answer here?

Comment: @Menachem Since you wrote that answer as well. On the third point "Eventually, the body will die again and the soul will spend the rest of eternity in Olam Haba" Does Olam Haba in this instance refer to gan eden or the olam haba after one dies or does it refer to olam haba as in the world of Mashiach? Because if death was still possible then sooner or later everyone would die and earth would probably be empty, so do the souls live down here? etc.